# Preventing types from unifying

Tags: haskell, types, unification

Given this wrapper around integers:

```
newtype MyProxy a = MyProxy Int

mkProxy :: Int -> MyProxy a
mkProxy a = MyProxy a

addProxy :: MyProxy a -> MyProxy a -> MyProxy  a
addProxy (MyProxy a1) (MyProxy a2) = MyProxy $ a1+a2
```

I can perform the following:

```
a = mkProxy 1
b = mkProxy 2
c = addProxy a b
```

because the phantom parameters will be unified.  But I want to prevent this unification and cause a type error on line `c`.

The ST monad uses rank2 types to achieve a similar effect.  I could probably do something similar by changing the type of `addProxy`.  But I specifically do not want to do this.  I want to annotate the `a` type variable somehow to prevent it from unifying on the `addProxy` call.

Is this possible in Haskell?  Is there a reason why such an option would be dangerous?

---

Edit:

Let me elaborate on a partial solution (requiring `-XScopedTypeVariables`).  I can rewrite the code above as:

```
c :: forall a1 a2. MyProxy a1
c = addProxy a b
    where
        a = mkProxy 1 :: MyProxy a1
        b = mkProxy 2 :: MyProxy a2
```

This correctly causes a type error on `c` because `a1` and `a2` cannot be unified.
But this has two drawbacks: `a` and `b` cannot be defined at the top level; and you must explicitly specify the resulting type of `mkProxy`.

Is it possible to fix these drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, at least not without specifying something more to `mkProxy`.

The way the ST monad works is by requiring the escaping computation to generate something of type `forall s. ST s a` which prevents `s` from appearing free in `a`.

In your case however, you're doing two identical computations so generating a different type for each could be used to do evil things. For example, if `mkInt 1` generated different types each time it was called,

```
class Evil a b c | a, b -> c where
  foo :: a -> b -> c

let x = mkProxy 1 in foo x x
```

Would be different than

```
 foo (mkProxy 1) (mkProxy 1)
```

and we've lost some very nice properties in our code.

We can however do some extra leg work and make the fact that `a` and `b` can't unify explicit

```
 {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

 data Nat = S Nat | Z
 data Proxy (n :: Nat) a = Proxy a

 based :: a -> Proxy Z a
 based = Proxy

 fresh :: Proxy n a -> a -> Proxy (S n) a
 fresh (Proxy _) a = Proxy a
```

So now you need to do something like

```
a = based 1

b = fresh a 2
```

Comment: I understand why the `foo` example would be bad if `mkProxy` returned different values (lots of optimizations become unsafe), but I don't see why it's bad that those return different types.  What becomes unsafe?

Comment: @MikeIzbicki We break referential transparency since we can prove use overlappinginstances + multiparametertypeclasses to distinguish between a let-lifted expression and manually inlining it. Essentially type classes let us tell the difference just as much as it returning different values

Answer (score 0):

I would think that existential type variables would be suitable for this.  Basically, two existential type variables created independently won't unify.  In the following `test` fails to typecheck because it can't unify the type variables of the two `MyProxy`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

newtype MyProxy a = MyProxy Int

data Exists f = forall a. Exists (f a)

mkProxy :: Int -> Exists MyProxy
mkProxy a = Exists (MyProxy a)

addProxy :: MyProxy a -> MyProxy a -> MyProxy a
addProxy (MyProxy a1) (MyProxy a2) = MyProxy $ a1+a2

test :: Exists MyProxy -> Exists MyProxy -> Exists MyProxy
test (Exists a) (Exists b) = Exists (addProxy a b)
```

Comment: I believe this works in essentially the same way as the ST monad trick.  The reason it's no good for me is that I want to use the `addProxy` function directly without a wrapper.